# iOS AudioToolbox crashes

Tags: ios, crash, audiotoolbox

I've some crashes in my application in AudioToolbox (AURemoteIO::IOThread), I don't know how to reproduce this crashes, but I have logs from Fabric. Maybe someone is faced with this issue, please help.

```
Thread : Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bd1c0 CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList + 119
1  AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bd045 AudioConverterConvertComplexBuffer + 268
2  AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bd045 AudioConverterConvertComplexBuffer + 268
3  AudioToolbox                   0x2a6139cd AUSpatialMixer::Render(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long) + 1212
4  AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bf6b9 AUBase::DoRenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, AUOutputElement*, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 144
5  AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bf54d AUBase::DoRender(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 724
6  AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bf26f AUMethodRender(void*, unsigned long*, AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList*) + 46
7  AudioToolbox                   0x2a690303 AUConverterBase::RenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 394
8  AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bf6b9 AUBase::DoRenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, AUOutputElement*, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 144
9  AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bf54d AUBase::DoRender(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 724
10 AudioToolbox                   0x2a685485 AURemoteIO::PerformIO(unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned int, AudioTimeStamp const&, AudioTimeStamp const&, AudioBufferList const*, AudioBufferList*, int&) + 492
11 AudioToolbox                   0x2a68653b AURIOCallbackReceiver_PerformIO + 394
12 AudioToolbox                   0x2a67e7b3 _XPerformIO + 166
13 AudioToolbox                   0x2a5dd90b mshMIGPerform + 190
14 AudioToolbox                   0x2a657735 MSHMIGDispatchMessage + 32
15 AudioToolbox                   0x2a685791 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 120
16 AudioToolbox                   0x2a688e3d AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 8
17 AudioToolbox                   0x2a5bb6c5 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39dbcddf _pthread_body + 138
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39dbcd53 _pthread_start + 118
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also frequent crashes in AudioToolbox since iOS 9.
I did open bug reports, but got no solutions, so I asked for developer help.

Apple wrote me on 06-Nov-2015:
"I have checked with engineering. The issue is still under investigation, and there is no resolution available yet."

So I am waiting for a solution or workaround to eliminate the crashes.
My bug report was closed because it was a duplicate, which shows that others have similar problems.

Comment: Sorry I still got no answer or workaround from Apple. It seems, that this bug is not important enough for Apple. The effect still occurs with iOS 9.3.2.

Comment: same here as of March 2018, in cocos2d sound engine, using openAl, see https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/17494